# Java replaceAll regex read from XML

Tags: java, regex, dom

So I have read 2 strings from an xml file. The xml string is:

```
<regex code="bla[. ]?(.*)\n" replacement="cpe_ip_learning_table:\\n$1\\n "/>
```

This reads into two separate variables for a replaceAll call. i.e:

```
str = str.replaceAll(code, replacement);
```

However, even when I try a \n as a replacement instead of a \\n it still does not insert a newline.

I am using a DOM DocumentBuilder to read the XML file into two separate strings. I have tried using Matcher.quoteReplacement as well to no avail. Has anyone run into this issue and how have they solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this same behavior also, and the only way I found to fix it was by doing a `replaceAll` on the replacement string itself:

```
rep = replacement.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n")
str = str.replaceAll(code, rep);
```

Strings returned by `DOMDocument` ignore newline (`\n`) constructs for some strange reason.

Comment: I'm curious why they do this though. Could it be because we use doc.normalize() ?

Comment: @bge0, `doc.normalize` doesn't appear to be the reason, for the behavior remains the same whether used or not. It's almost as if the `replaceAll` pattern expects `literal newlines` to be in the `replacement` string, which could only be represented by including a physical carriage return in the places you've got the construct `\n` ([see here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f705fe4aa728729e8af3)); that definitely doesn't seem right either.